# How to measure accuracy of a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

I have this Neural Network for a specific data set:

```
    crossnet1 = 
  NetChain[{LinearLayer[9], ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], LinearLayer[8], 
    ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], LinearLayer[7], ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], 
    LinearLayer[6], ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], LinearLayer[5], 
    ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], LinearLayer[4], ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], 
    LinearLayer[3], ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], LinearLayer[2], 
    ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], LinearLayer[1]}, "Input" -> {9}];
trainedcross1 = 
 NetTrain[crossnet1, data, BatchSize -> 300, MaxTrainingRounds -> 30]
```

Now I would like to measure its accuracy. I found that I can use `NetMeasurement` and `"Accuracy"` but I don't really understand how. I thought I could say `NetMeasurements[trainedcross1, data, "Accuracy"]`, but it gives an error for this. I could not find much information about it online.

Comment: It appears you are building a regression model (rather than a classifier) as your output is a linear layer and you don't specify a loss function in `NetTrain` it will choose `MeanSquaredLossLayer`)  ...and so consequently "Accuracy" is not a valid measurement to perform.  You could of course replace "Accuracy" with "RSquared" in your `NetMeasurements`...or add an appropriate loss layer (e.g., `CrossEntropyLossLayer`) to your network to convert it to a classifier.

Comment: Thank you @JoshuaSchrier. So the "RSquared" is doing the same thing as "Accuracy"? Just to make sure that get the correct accuracy of the network...

Comment: I'm way out of my area here but I do use neural nets in some work even if I fail to understand the inner workings. That stated, the only accuracy measure I would trust is from withholding some of the data from training, and checking the predicted vs actual results on this withheld data.

Comment: @FelipeAmorim It's what Joshua Schrier is mentioning. Also the documentation claims accuracy needs the CrossEntropyLossLayer as a losslayer. You could show some of your data etc to help people to better understand your problem. Also https://www.wolfram.com/language/introduction-machine-learning/ is a very well written book detailing alot! You can read it for free.

Comment: @FelipeAmorim:  Accuracy is a measurement for categorical outcomes (i.e., how often does a true/false model prediction agree with a true/false ground truth).  As  RSquared, etc. are ways of determining the correlation between numerical values (i.e., how well does the models prediction of a set of numerical output values agree with the true numerical output values).  I second Lou's recommendation to work through the intro tutorial.